# Android Screen goes blank on orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

I've developed a tabbed application with two tabs, say **Audio** and **Video**.

On orientation change I made the tabs to orient at the left hand side of the device.

But on changing the `orientation` the `activity`(which i gave a `textview`) goes blank.

I want the `activity` to be displayed on `orientation change`.

I put `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` to the activity element in the manifest file because I don't want the tab activity to be recreated.

Could anyone please post a way to sort this issue out?

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity implements
        TabHost.TabContentFactory {
```

`TabHost tabHost;
Intent intent;
Intent intent2;
Resources res;
Configuration cfg;
boolean hor;
boolean ver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onCreate Maintab");
    res = getResources();
    cfg = res.getConfiguration();
    hor = cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    ver = cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    if (hor) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view_land);
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabWidget tw = tabHost.getTabWidget();
        tw.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorViewLand(tabHost, "Audio",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1)))
                .setContent(intent));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorViewLand(tabHost, "Video",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2)))
                .setContent(intent2));
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
                }
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);

            }
        });
    } else if (ver) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorView(tabHost, "Audio",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1)))
                .setContent(intent));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorView(tabHost, "Video",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2)))
                .setContent(intent2));
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
                }
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);
            }
        });
    }
}
private View createIndicatorView(TabHost tabHost, CharSequence label,
        Drawable icon) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View tabIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,
            tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv.setText(label);
    final ImageView iconView = (ImageView) tabIndicator
            .findViewById(R.id.icon);
    iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);
    return tabIndicator;
}
private View createIndicatorViewLand(TabHost tabHost, CharSequence label,
        Drawable icon) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View tabIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_land,
            tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv.setText(label);
    final ImageView iconView = (ImageView) tabIndicator
            .findViewById(R.id.icon);
    iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);
    return tabIndicator;
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    System.out.println("onCOnfig MainTab");
    res = getResources();
    cfg = res.getConfiguration();
    hor = cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    ver = cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    if (hor) {
        System.out.println("onCOnfig Horizontal");
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view_land);
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabWidget tw = tabHost.getTabWidget();
        tw.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        // intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        // intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorViewLand(tabHost, "Audio",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1)))
                .setContent(intent));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorViewLand(tabHost, "Video",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2)))
                .setContent(intent2));
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
                }
                tabHost.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                        .setBackgroundResource(
                                R.drawable.audio_video_sellected);
            }
        });
    } else if (ver) {
        System.out.println("onCOnfig Vertical");
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        // intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        // intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorView(tabHost, "Audio",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1)))
                .setContent(intent));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator(
                        createIndicatorView(tabHost, "Video",
                                getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2)))
                .setContent(intent2));
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_default);
                }
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_sellected);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public View createTabContent(String tag) {
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Content for tab with tag " + tag);
    return tv;
}`

}

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: couldn't get a clue from it :(

Comment: Post your activity code...

Comment: android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" is to avoid unless you have a very good reason to do so. Recreating the activity is the normal lifecycle when the screen is rotated, simply put the data you want to keep in a bundle.

Comment: In Activity1 and Activity2, i have a list of items with checkboxes. On orientation change the checked items are getting reset. Inorder to avoid that I used android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation".